# How to install Cloud Foundry CLI on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry, boot2docker

I am a docker newbie.

I have an ubuntu image and wanted to install Cloud Foundry CLI on it and am unable to do so.

I downloaded the binary for CF CLI from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases  and untarred it. The untar is successful but I am unable to run the CLI.

When i run the cf i get /bin/sh: ./cf: not found message.

Answer (score 4):

A couple ways to do this.  Edit your path.  Place the following in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/containingcf
```

Or put `cf` in `/usr/bin/` or somewhere that is already on your path.

Answer (score 0):

If cf executable in current directory just use "./cf".
In general it is better to place cf executable somewhere in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the cf file has executable permissions and it is suitable for your OS architecture (e.g. Boot2Docker 1.5.0 works only with "Linux 32 bit" cf binary).